Flink 1.18 runtime java 17 support
I have a Kinesis stream on AWS, and the runtime I'm using is Flink 1.18. When I tried to compile my application code in Java 17 and start the stream, I encountered the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: KinesisToSqsStreamingJob has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0.
Does this mean that Flink does not yet support Java 17?
Compiled the kinesis application code in Java 17

The project tracker conveys that it should be delivered but in beta. Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your application to help identify the cause of what you are facing as an issue? Most likely the runtime of your application is not rightly configured yet for the Java version expected.

I checked the configs again and i can see these is only one option for runtime - Runtime Apache Flink 1.18, there is no other option to specify the runtime where i can use java 17.
